# Difference between using New-ADUser with hashtable and PSCustomObject

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I tried to automate creating AD users in my lab environment and came across an interesting issue that I cannot seem to grasp. When I tried using the following code, Powershell threw "New-ADUser : The name provided is not a properly formed account name"

```
$Attributes = @{
    Enabled = $true
    ChangePasswordAtLogon = $false
    Departent = "MyDepartment"
    UserPrincipalNAme = "first.name@domain.lel"
    City = "MySite"
    DisplayName = "My display name"
    EmailAddress = "My@mail.address"
    GivenName = "First Name"
    Manager = "cbu"
    PasswordNeverExpires = $true
    SamAccountName = "abc123"
    Surname = "Last name"
    Title = "Title"
    Name = "abc123"
    AccountPassword = $("Thishere1234" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)
}

New-ADUser $Attributes
```

The above example is close to a copy paste from some post that I found using hashtables as a way to pass the information to New-ADUser. Since this did not work, I instead tried the following:

```
$Attributes = [pscustomobject]@{
    Enabled = $true
    ChangePasswordAtLogon = $false
    Departent = "MyDepartment"
    UserPrincipalNAme = "first.name@domain.lel"
    City = "MySite"
    DisplayName = "My display name"
    EmailAddress = "My@mail.address"
    GivenName = "First Name"
    Manager = "cbu"
    PasswordNeverExpires = $true
    SamAccountName = "abc123"
    Surname = "Last name"
    Title = "Title"
    Name = "abc123"
    AccountPassword = $("Thishere1234" | ConvertTo-SecureString -AsPlainText -Force)
}
$Attributes | New-ADUser
```

This works just fine. My question is: why would the first hashtable approach not accept the name property but the second PSCustomObject does accept the exact same approach?

As a bonus question, is there any particular reason I cannot use New-ADUser $Attributes but rather I have to pipe $Attributes to New-ADUser? I was under the impression you could use the former too?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When splatting using a hashtable, you need to use the `@` sign on the cmdlet, not a `$`:

```
New-ADUser @Attributes
```

Comment: Oooh, did not know that! Thanks :) Do you also happen to know why I can use New-ADUser @Attributes when it's a hashtable but not New-ADUser $Attributes when I'm using a PSCustomObject?

Comment: @MagneTism Well.. that is simply how [Splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_splatting) in PowerShell works. It expects a Hashtable using the `@hash` syntax

Comment: Let me rephrase: what's wrong with using New-ADUser $Attributes when $Attributes is a [PSCustomObject]?